# Parse below XML in Sql Server getting errror

Tags: sql-server, xml

The XML looks like this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<saw:choose xmlns:saw="aaa">
<saw:when condition="true">
<saw:deliveryContent format="excel2007" disposition="attachment">
<saw:headline>
<saw:caption>
<saw:text>Test Mail from bjri-obi-004</saw:text>
</saw:caption>
</saw:headline>
<saw:reportRef path="/shared/BJs Analytics/Agent/Reports/Dana DO & RVP"/>
-<saw:attachmentMessage>
-<saw:caption>
<saw:text>DO & RVP Report</saw:text>
</saw:caption>
</saw:attachmentMessage>
</saw:deliveryContent>
<saw:postActions/>
</saw:when>
-<saw:otherwise>
<saw:postActions/>
</saw:otherwise>
</saw:choose>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('aaa' as saw)
SELECT
 @xml.value('(saw:choose/saw:when/saw:headline/saw:caption/saw:text)[1]','nvarchar(max)')as Textname
```

Getting Error

```
Msg 9421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 9, character 69, illegal name character
```

And when I replace `&` with `&amp;`, then it returns `null` value.

My result table should contain

```
text="Test Mail from bjri-obi-004"
path="/shared/BJs Analytics/Agent/Reports/Dana DO & RVP"
text="DO & RVP Report"
```

Comment: `&` should be replaced by `&amp;` instead of `&and;`.

Comment: then only i am getting NULL value

Answer (score 0):

A couple of fixes are needed. All `&` characters should be encoded as `&amp;`. Also, your path is invalid: `saw:deliveryContent is missing. See fixed example below.

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saw:choose xmlns:saw="aaa">
<saw:when condition="true">
<saw:deliveryContent format="excel2007" disposition="attachment">
<saw:headline>
<saw:caption>
<saw:text>Test Mail from bjri-obi-004</saw:text>
</saw:caption>
</saw:headline>
<saw:reportRef path="/shared/BJs Analytics/Agent/Reports/Dana DO &amp; RVP"/>
-<saw:attachmentMessage>
-<saw:caption>
<saw:text>DO &amp; RVP Report</saw:text>
</saw:caption>
</saw:attachmentMessage>
</saw:deliveryContent>
<saw:postActions/>
</saw:when>
-<saw:otherwise>
<saw:postActions/>
</saw:otherwise>
</saw:choose>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('aaa' as saw)
SELECT
 @xml.value('(saw:choose/saw:when/saw:deliveryContent/saw:headline/saw:caption/saw:text)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as Textname
```

Comment: excellent, short and to the point. i was able to utilize this without much thought which is always nice :-)

Comment: WHen i insert this in my xml "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"     Following Error come:                                                                                                 Msg 9438, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 2, character 6, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input 
can you help me in this ?

Comment: I've added xml declaration and it works fine. Make sure there are no other tags before `<?xml..` (xml declaration must go first) and there are no additional things in your xml. Copy solution above and see if it works.